# Where is etcd config file in Mac OS

Tags: macos, homebrew, etcd

I have installed etcd in my mac using brew. I know we can pass the custom config file when starting the etcd using --config-file flag but I am not able to locate the default config file of etcd. So could you please let me know the location of the default config file of etcd?

Answer (score 1):

By reading the Homebrew formula/package definition of `etcd`. It doesn't include any default config file.